# Wordpress server error when activating new theme

Tags: wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

Every time I activate a theme I have downloaded, I get a server error 500

This has happened on many different themes, not just one. Most recently used Starkers which is a trusted theme I have used many times before.

Once I activate, error 500, and I can't access Wordpress again until I FTP up and delete the theme folder.

Comment: There must be something wrong with the theme. Have you tried setting `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in your config ?

Answer (score 0):

> This has happened on many different themes, not just one...

Obviously a host issue; who is the host? Same host that Starkers does work on?

What does debug say, if anything?

Comment: It is daily.co.uk, my own host, who work just fine with basic WP themes and I have used for ages...